# Retrieve/Parse values from Json(deserialised) Object. Can anyone please assist?

Tags: c#

Need assistance in retrieving values from a JSON object in C#
Below is the code and my output. I am trying to retrieve value of `ScoreRepresentation` from both the objects. The retrieved values in this case would be `BR400L` and `null` as per the below **output**.

Can anyone please assist. Newbie in C# :)
thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = "{\"Results\":[{\"RequestIdentifier\":\"Lexile\",\"ValueType\":\"INTEGER\",\"Scores\":[{\"lexile\":{\"ScoreValue\":-400,\"ScaledScore\":-400,\"ScoreRepresentation\":\"BR400L\"}}]},{\"RequestIdentifier\":\"UnifiedScaleScore\",\"ValueType\":\"INTEGER\",\"Scores\":[{\"unifiedScaleScore\":{\"ScoreValue\":610,\"ScaledScore\":610,\"ScoreRepresentation\":null}}]}]}";

            var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            Console.WriteLine(deserialized);

        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
  "Results": [
    {
      "RequestIdentifier": "Lexile",
      "ValueType": "INTEGER",
      "Scores": [
        {
          "lexile": {
            "ScoreValue": -400,
            "ScaledScore": -400,
            "ScoreRepresentation": "BR400L"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "RequestIdentifier": "UnifiedScaleScore",
      "ValueType": "INTEGER",
      "Scores": [
        {
          "unifiedScaleScore": {
            "ScoreValue": 610,
            "ScaledScore": 610,
            "ScoreRepresentation": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you should pass the types to `DeserializeObject`. something that models the json

Comment: You could also use JsonPath to query the object : https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm

Comment: You should heed Daniel's advice. your life becomes much easier when you `DeserializeObject<SomeModel>()`

Comment: @Andy can you please help me with that(if that is not too much to ask) . I have no idea how to model it.

Comment: @DanielA.White ^^